# Update Edittext when other Edittext change

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to update a single `EditText` based off other `EditTexts`. For some reason everything works fine until I have to set the text then I get a continuous list of errors. I can't seem to find out why or if this is the best practice. Any help would be appreciated. If I comment the setting of the text out. My app works fine. This is my code:

```
 final Boolean[] hasValue = {false};
    ArrayList<EditText> editTexts = new ArrayList<>(); // Container list
    ArrayList<Double> values = new ArrayList<>(); // value list
    editTexts.add(IBalance); // editTexts[0]
    editTexts.add(Trading); // editTexts[1]
    editTexts.add(Binary); // editTexts[2]
    editTexts.add(Referrals); // editTexts[3]
    editTexts.add(Leader1); // editTexts[4]
    editTexts.add(Leader2); // editTexts[5]
    editTexts.add(Deposit); // editTexts[6]
    editTexts.add(Withdrawal); // editTexts[7]
    editTexts.add(Total); // editTexts[8]

    for (final EditText editText : editTexts) { //need to be final for custom behaviors
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                /*if (editText.getText().toString().equals("0")) {
                    editText.setText("");

                }*/
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (editText.getText().toString().equals("") || editText.getText().toString().equals("0")) {
                    editText.setText("0.0");
                    editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
                }
                else if(editText.getText().toString().equals("0.0"))
                    editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                values.add(Double.parseDouble(IBalance.getText().toString())); //[0]
                values.add(Double.parseDouble(Trading.getText().toString())); //[1]
                values.add(Double.parseDouble(Binary.getText().toString())); //[2]
                values.add(Double.parseDouble(Referrals.getText().toString())); //[3]
                values.add(Double.parseDouble(Leader1.getText().toString())); //[4]
                values.add(Double.parseDouble(Leader2.getText().toString())); //[5]
                values.add(Double.parseDouble(Deposit.getText().toString())); //[6]
                values.add(Double.parseDouble(Withdrawal.getText().toString())); //[7]
                for (final Double db : values) {
                    hasValue[0] = db != null;
                }
                double total = 0;
                if(hasValue[0]=true)
                {
                    total = values.get(0)+values.get(1)+values.get(2)+values.get(3)+values.get(4)+values.get(5)+values.get(6)-values.get(0);
//ERROR OCCURS      Total.setText(String.valueOf(total)); //ERROR OCCURS
                }
                values.clear();
            }
        });
    }
```

And this is a screen of error in the run console:[image: erorr]

It repeats itself for so long that the beginning of the error is cut off. this is how the app looks:

[image: app]

Comment: `Total` is part of your `for` loop and you are setting `Total` in `afterTextChanged`, so your loop will never end. Try removing `editTexts.add(Total);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, that you also add `total` to your List. That's why total gets also the Listener.

Setting the text of an EditText within its own Listener creates an endless loop.

Remove this line

```
editTexts.add(Total); // editTexts[8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your checking whether the values are null is incorrect.

1. Replace `boolean[] hasValue = {false}` with `boolean hasValue = true`.
2. Instead of this,

```
for (final Double db : values) {
    hasValue[0] = db != null;
}
```

Use this:

```
for (final Double db : values) {
    if (db == null) {
        hasValue = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

This is because in the original one, you edited hasValue to depend only on the last element of values.

Also, in the `total = ...` line, you used `values.get(0)-values.get(0)`. This aroused my curiosity.

Comment: This is absolutely correct, but not the reason for the shown error

Comment: Thank you for the advice and finding a mistake in my calculation!